# Error "No view found for id" al tratar de abrir un Fragment en android

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

tengo un problema a tratar de cargar un fragmento, uso un navigation drawer, donde tengo diferentes opciones:[image: Navigation Drawer]
Cuando yo de clic a la pestaña de Facebook, tiene que abrir un fragmento, el prolema es que cuando doy clic en la opcion la aplicacion se cierra, el error que muestra es:

```js
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d008b (com.example.enriq.interfaces_de_usuario_enrique_espinosa:id/fragmentf) for fragment facebookfragment{5cdf54f #0 id=0x7f0d008b}
```

Este es el codigo de mi MainActivity:

```js
package com.example.enriq.interfaces_de_usuario_enrique_espinosa;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.Versionw) {
                return true;
            }
            else if (id == R.id.Compartir) {

            } else if (id == R.id.Configurar) {

            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.hometap) {
                // Handle the camera action
            } else if (id == R.id.facetap) {
                facebookfragment facebook = new facebookfragment();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentf, facebook).commit();

            } else if (id == R.id.instatap) {

            } else if (id == R.id.twittertap) {

            } else if (id == R.id.googletap) {

            }

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Este es el activity_main:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Y el codigo de mi fragment es el siguiente:

```js
package com.example.enriq.interfaces_de_usuario_enrique_espinosa;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class facebookfragment extends Fragment {


    public facebookfragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_facebookfragment, container, false);
    }

}
```

y por ultimo el layout de mi fragmento:

```js
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentf"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.enriq.interfaces_de_usuario_enrique_espinosa.facebookfragment">


</RelativeLayout>
```

No se porque me marca ese error.

Comment: Estas utilizando la plantilla que trae en Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error esta en que el id que usas en el replace() debe de ser del contenedor en el que se desea colocar el Fragmento.

Agrega un **id** en el archivo **content_main.xml**

```
android:id="@+id/contenedor_principal"
```

Y en tu MainActivity quedaria de esta forma:

```
facebookfragment facebook = new facebookfragment();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager =   getSupportFragmentManager();
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor_principal, facebook).commit();
```

Con esto deberia de funcionar.

Comment: Si, me di cuenta que estaba mal el id que coloque, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: De nada @Kike hatake saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que hay que definir el content_menu.xml con un ID ej:android:id="+@id/content_main", ya que Navigation Drawer tiene uno propio y no necesita de activity_main.xml para referenciar.

Answer (score 0):

En el archivo activity.xml se encuentra incluido el layout app_bar_main

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

lo mas seguro es que en app_bar_main.xml se encuentre incluido el content_main

```
<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>
```

Si tiene incluido lo anterio revisa en el archivo content_main.xml a ver si tiene lo siguiente

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

</FrameLayout>
```

si no lo tiene agregalo, ya hecho esto tenemos la seguridad que existe el container que sera reemplazado por los fragmento que quieras. ya que al momento que es asignado en el MainActivity con

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

lo podemos llamar y reemplazar. yo creo un metodo para hacer esto.

```
 protected boolean openFragment(Fragment fragment){
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content, fragment)
            .commit();
    return true;
}
```

y lo llamo donde lo necesite en tu caso en onNavigationItemSelected queda asi

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.hometap)
        else if (id == R.id.facetap) openFragment(new facebookfragment());
        else if (id == R.id.instatap) 
        else if (id == R.id.twittertap) 
        else if (id == R.id.googletap) 

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```